# Accidentally deleted openssl lib packages and can't get yum or wget to work again in redhat 6.10

Tags: rhel, libraries

I have accidentally deleted the `openssl` lib packages and can't get `yum` or `wget` to work again in RHEL 6.10.

I am missing:

- libssl.so.10
- libcrypto.so.10

Comment: Welcome to this community. While many would understand that you probably want to reinstall these libraries, please be specific about the situation you want to achieve. Please have a look at [the help centre](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) for future guidance. You may also want to discover the features of markdown to enhance the formatting of your post; if the reviewers accept my edit, you can come back to the raw form of your post and see how you code them into your text.

Comment: You could install the same system in a different machine - or in a virtual machine, then copy the files over. Or, easier, download the rpm file and unpack it. Or, run a live system and install from there.

Comment: Hi , the wget or scp is not working and getting lost connection error when i tried to connect from other VM

Comment: @harishhari Please add in the post extra information you mentioned such as the **errors** you get. You may re-edit your post at will: to do so click on 'edit' under the text. This action will help the readers to grasp at once what you're looking for; it will increase your readership and your chance to get a precise reply quickly.

Comment: `/usr/lib64/{libcrypto.so.10 -> libcrypto.so.1.0.1e, libssl.so.10 -> libssl.so.1.0.1e}` .... Package : http://mirror.centos.org/centos/6.10/updates/x86_64/Packages/openssl-1.0.1e-58.el6_10.x86_64.rpm ..... unPack_rpm.sh : https://drive.google.com/file/d/1q3d9QqrRhEThYByPDgWEaoxHnqWFWqfE/view?usp=sharing